# C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list.

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I am trying to finish a lab assignment from edx, but I cannot figure out why my code won't work. The assignment requires to create a Student class, Teacher class, and Course class. I am trying to figure out the Course class Constructor, but it will not accept my Teacher object. I use a pointer to create the objects so that I allocate space in memory for it (one of the things I learned on edx, tell me if I misunderstood). So I tried to use reference in the constructor, but it still did not work. Here is the code. I use "unknown" as filler.

Main code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
#include "Teacher.h"
#include "Course.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Teacher *teach = new Teacher("Jane", "DoeDoe", 25, "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown");
    Student *stud1 = new Student();
    Student *stud2 = new Student("John", "Doe", 19, "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown");
    Student *stud3 = new Student("Jane", "Doe", 23, "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown");
    //Method had two postions. First and Last
    stud1->setName("Unknown", "Unknown");
    stud1->setAge(20);
    stud1->setAddress("Unknown");
    stud1->setCity("Unknown");
    stud1->setPhone("Unknown");

    Course *c = new Course("Intermediate C++", teach, stud1, stud2, stud3);


    return 0;
}
```

Course.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include "Teacher.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Course {
private:
    string name;
    Teacher teacher;
    Student student1;
    Student student2;
    Student student3;


public:


    Course(string n, Teacher &t, Student &s1, Student &s2, Student &s3);

    ~Course();


};
```

Course.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Course.h"



Course::Course(string n, Teacher &t, Student &s1, Student &s2, Student &s3)
{
    name = n;
    teacher = t;
    student1 = s1;
    student2 = s2;
    student3 = s3;

}

Course::~Course()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Course(string n, Teacher &t, Student &s1, Student &s2, Student &s3);
```

expects you to pass references to `t`,`s1`, `s2`..

```
Course *c = new Course("Intermediate C++", teach, stud1, stud2, stud3);
```

Here you pass `teach` which is a `teacher*`. You want to

```
Course *c = new Course("Intermediate C++", *teach, *stud1, *stud2, *stud3);
```

You might want to read more about [references and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)